# Sing, Elton! - Blog article mistypes

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

[In this blog article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/10/13/why-solve-a-problem-twice-design-patterns-let-you-apply-existing-solutions-to-your-code), Singleton is mistyped twice.

[image: The third and fourth instance of 'Singleton' in the image is misspelled as 'Singelton'.]

[image: Elton John in front of a piano.]

Comment: Did they disable comments on the blog posts again?

Comment: Too bad creator of the image didn't buy the keyboard that let copy&paste. ;)

Comment: @CodyGray looks like we can comment, but question is whether it's appropriate to post such bug report as comment on the blog post, or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the catch (and the pun), @Tamás Sengel. I've updated it with a new image from the author. In the future, you can comment directly on the article and it'll get to me directly.

Comment: They should just have added this image.